# Mirroring the position when moving objects from the array to the array to another object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

When I call the `createTodo` function,`this.state.todos` is added to the new todo. Objects with the `time` property want to move to the`times` array in object `select`, but`times` are doubled.
I think the blame is the .slice method and copying the array. How to get around it?

**Todo**

```
class Todo extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
       <li>
        <div>
          {this.props.todo.description}
        </div>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {

      todos: [
        {
          time: '00:00:10',
          description: 'Hello'
        },
        {
          time: '00:00:20',
          description: 'World'
        }
       ],
      todo: {
        'time': '00:00:30',
        'description': 'W'
      },
      select: {
        "times": [{ 'time': '00:00:40' }, { 'time': '00:00:50' }],
        "description": " ytytyty",
        "id": 3,
        "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"
      }
     };
  }



  addTodo = (todo) => {
    const news = this.state.todos.slice();
    news.push(this.state.todo);
    this.setState({ todos: news });
  };


  render() {

    this.state.todos.forEach(t => {
      if (t.time) this.state.select.times.push({
        time: t.time
      })
    });

    console.log(this.state.todos);
    console.log(this.state.select);

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.todos
              .map((todo, index) =>
                <Todo
                  key={index}
                  index={index}
                  todo={todo}
                />
              )
          }
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.createTodo}>button</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

console.log(this.state.select) -> return-->

times: [
 {time: "00:00:40"}
 {time: "00:00:50"}
 {time: "00:00:10"} //repeat
 {time: "00:00:20"} //repeat
 {time: "00:00:10"}
 {time: "00:00:20"}
 {time: "00:00:30"}
 title: "gfgfgfgfgf"
]
```

**Expecting effect**:

```
times: [
     {time: "00:00:40"}
     {time: "00:00:50"}
     {time: "00:00:10"}
     {time: "00:00:20"}
     {time: "00:00:30"}
     title: "gfgfgfgfgf"
    ]
```

**DEMO** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jfkwnu

When the component is loaded it should be: `selectTodo: {"times": [{'time': '00: 00: 40 '}, {' time ':' 00: 00: 50 '}], "description": "ytytyty", "id": 3, "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"}`

First click button: -> `selectTodo: {times: [{time: "00:00:40"} {time: "00:00:50"} {time: "00:00:10"} {time: " 00:00:20 "} {time:" 00:00:30 "} title:" gfgfgfgfgf "]," description ":" ytytyty "," id ": 3," title ":" gfgfgfgfgf "}`

Second click button change -> `selectTodo: {times: [{time: "00:00:40"} {time: "00:00:50"} {time: "00:00:10"} {time: "00 : 00: 20 "} {'time': '00: 00: 30'}, {time:" 00:00:30 "} title:" gfgfgfgfgf "]" description ":" ytytyty "," id ": 3 , "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"}`

Comment: Isn't there an error in the _expected effect_ example you gave?

Comment: @ dashdashzako. No errors. I think the problem is method slice(copy new array)

Comment: @dashdashzako Did you delete your answer?

Comment: Yes I think I'm missing something.
If you push `todos` without emptying it, its values will always be pushed to the `times`, which is kind of expected. Can you clarify if todos should persist or if it can be emptied between each `addTodo` call?

Comment: @ dashdashzako Can you create any example? I would like to see how it works

Comment: @dashdashzako I think `todos` should be persist

Comment: The problem is that you are manipulating `state.select.times` in the `render` method - `render` should be pure! Either do the state manipulation in `addTodo`, or make `selectTimes` a local variable within the `render` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to maintain both `todos` and `selectTodo` independently, but always have all `todos` times mirrored to `selectTodo.times`.

To sum up:

1. component state is set in constructor
2. component mounts
3. when user creates a todo

   1. if this is the first time, existing `todos` are mirrored to `selectTodo.times`
   2. push the new todo to `todos` and `selectTodo.times`.

To know if user has already used the `createTodo` method, I just added the `withInitialTodos` to the state. It's not really clean, but it does the job for what you need.

Note that as Bergi said in a comment above, you should avoid updating the state in the `render` method.

```js
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        withInitialTodos: true,
        todos: [
            {
                time: '00:00:10',
                description: 'Hello'
            },
            {
                time: '00:00:20',
                description: 'World'
            }
        ],
        todo: {
            'time': '00:00:30',
            'description': 'W'
        },
        selectTodo: {
            "times": [{ 'time': '00:00:40' }, { 'time': '00:00:50' }],
            "description": " ytytyty",
            "id": 3,
            "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"
        }
    };
}

createTodo = (todo) => {
    this.setState({
        withInitialTodos: false,
        todos: [].concat(this.state.todos, this.state.todo),
        selectTodo: {
            ...this.state.selectTodo,
            times: [].concat(
                this.state.selectTodo.times,
                this.state.withInitialTodos ? this.state.todos.map(({ time }) => ({ time })): [],
                {
                  time: this.state.todo.time
                }
            )
        }
    });
}

render() {

    console.log(this.state.todos);
    console.log(this.state.selectTodo.times);

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.state.todos.map((todo, index) => (
                    <Todo
                      key={index}
                      index={index}
                      todo={todo}
                    />
                )}
            </ul>
            <button onClick={this.createTodo}></button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: when the component is loaded it should be: selectTodo: {
         "times": [{'time': '00: 00: 40 '}, {' time ':' 00: 00: 50 '}],
         "description": "ytytyty",
         "id": 3,
         "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"
       }

Comment: press button change --> selectTodo: {
        times: [
     {time: "00:00:40"}
     {time: "00:00:50"}
     {time: "00:00:10"}
     {time: "00:00:20"}
     {time: "00:00:30"}
     title: "gfgfgfgfgf"
    ],
        "description": " ytytyty",
        "id": 3,
        "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"
      }

Comment: Ah, so you only want to add the `todos` if the button is pressed. I'd then use a kind of toggle in the state, I'll update the answer.

Comment: yes. I click another button change -> selectTodo: {
         times: [
      {time: "00:00:40"}
      {time: "00:00:50"}
      {time: "00:00:10"}
      {time: "00:00:20"}
      {'time': '00: 00: 30 '},
      {time: "00:00:30"}
      title: "gfgfgfgfgf"
     ]
         "description": "ytytyty",
         "id": 3,
         "title": "gfgfgfgfgf"
       }

Comment: every click adds another todo

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should work fine even though it's not the cleanest way to achieve it.